# Euler characteristic of open varieties as degree of Chern class of logarithmic differentials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $U$ be a smooth variety over a subfield $k$ of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety containing $U$ as the complement of a normal crossings divisor $D$. Denote by $\chi(U)$ the Euler characteristic of $U$, defined using either de Rham cohomology or singular cohomology of the complex analytic manifold attached to $U$. Let $\Omega^1_X(\log D)$ be the sheaf of logarithmic differentials. If $X$ has dimension $n$, then it is locally free of rank $n$ and one has the equality
$$
\chi(U)=\deg c_n(\Omega^1_X(\log D))
$$

This is quite easy to prove using the Riemann-Roch theorem, but I have been unable to find a written proof. Can anybody provide a reference that I can cite in a paper?

Answer (score 3):

A simple explaination of the equivalent dual statement, i.e. using $T_X(- \log D)$ instead of $\Omega^1(\log D),$ can be found in the book by Burt Totaro *[Group cohomology and algebraic cycles](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/group-cohomology-and-algebraic-cycles)*, page 25.

The corresponding link on googlebooks is [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=bXCFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=Euler%20number%20logarithmic%20bundle&source=bl&ots=jzUbqZgxpF&sig=NKvrWLctFGzAWWIjLXji95i3uns&hl=it&sa=X&ei=sw9BVM_vCtThatyKgdgN&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Euler%20number%20logarithmic%20bundle&f=false).

I am sure that it can be found in many other places, anyway this is just the first explicit reference I can remember now.

Comment: Thank you Francesco! Do you know of any more standard reference?

Comment: You are welcome. Well, in the other few books that I checked, I did not find the explicit computation of $\chi(U)$ in terms of $c_n$ of the logarithmic (co)tangent bundle. I think that the original computation is due to Deligne (maybe Theorie de Hodge II?), you should try and look there.